# Evaluate if $f_{_n}$ converge uniformly or not

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

We have $f_n:[1,2]\to \mathbb{R},\:f_n(x)=\frac{x^n}{x^n+1}$ and we have to see if the convergence is uniform or not.

From what I understand we need to prove that $\lim _{n\to \infty } \sup_{x\in[1,2]} |f_n(x)-f(x)| =0$ to show that $f_n$ converges uniformly.

I don't understand how we calculate $\sup_{x\in[1,2]} |f_n(x)-f(x)|$.

Here is all my steps: $f_n(x)\rightarrow 1,\:f(x)=1$ so 
$$|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\left|\frac{x^n}{\left(x^n+1\right)}-1\right|=\left|\frac{-1}{x^n+1}\right|=\frac{1}{x^n+1}$$

and now we have to find $\sup_{x\in[1,2]} \frac1{x^n+1}$. How do we do that? How we find supremum of this function?

Comment: I've fixed your notation to be standard. As a general advice, try to avoid `\left` and `\right` unless necessary. The usual notation for a supremum is as you see it now: $\sup_{x\in A} f(x)$, in MathJax `\sup_{x\in A} f(x)`

Comment: I will do it, was my first time, thanks for edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some ideas:

$$\frac{x^n}{x^n+1}=1-\frac1{x^n+1}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1\;,\;\;\forall\;x\in (1,2]$$

Yet, for $\;x=1\;$ , we have

$$\frac{1^n}{1^n+1}=\frac12\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac12$$

So the limit function isn't continuous...yet **for all** $\;n\; ,\;\ f_n\;$ is, and then...

Comment: Timbuc, I don't understand why the limit function isn't continuous... what I know is that to prove a function is continous we need to show that $ls=ld=f(x_{_0})$

Comment: can you explain it in more detail?

Comment: Lucas: if a sequence of *continuous* functions converges *uniformly* on some given interval, then the limit function is **also** continuous. And the limit function in this case isn't continuous because it is a constant on $\;(1,2]\;$ **and it equals a different number** on $\;x=1\;$

Comment: and which is the constant on $(1,2]$ ? is 0?

Comment: @Lucas Have you read my answer *at all* ?!

Comment: @Lucas (1) What does your last question have to do with your original question above (cominated convergence, integral...) ? (2) Read and understand my answer !

Comment: @Lucas "I say" ? Isn't it **obvious** from what I, and others, already wrote?

Comment: I think you want to say that $f_n\left(1\right)\ne \lim _{n\to \infty }f_n\left(x\right)$, sorry man I am fool... there is no point to continue

Comment: @Lucas This stuff is usually studied in Calculus II or even Calculus III, depending where you're studying and *what* you're studying. It seems reasonable to assume you already had a course in Calculus I at the very least, and yes: you seem a little lost in this. I't not about being a fool or not, but about **you** going to the basics now that the semester isn't yet close to its end and try to catch up with the basic terminology, definitions, etc. In the web itself you have thousands of sites and papers free for you to work out this. Just google "uniform convergence of functions". Good luck.

Comment: hmm I read again your comment and now I think I understand what you want to say:  $\lim \:_{n\to \:\infty \:}f_n\left(x\right)=1$ when $\:x=1$ and for $x\in (1,2]$ we obtain other value wich is not equal with 1, and for the function $f_n$ to be uniform convergence, this means that it should not depend of x, and in our case depends on the value of x, I've right?

Comment: @Lucas Not exactly: $\;f_n(x)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1\;,\;\;\forall\,x\in(1,2]\;$ , whereas $\;f_n(1)=\frac12\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac12\;$ . Thus, the limit function is $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1&,\;\;x\in(1,2]\\{}\\\frac12&,\;\;x=1\end{cases}$$ which isn't continuous and thus the convergence **cannot** be uniform.

Comment: Just I want to say... and isn't continuous because depends on the value of x? and the limit are not equal

Comment: @L It isn't continuous because it doesn't fulfill the definition: $$\lim_{x\to 1^+}f(x)=1\neq\frac12=f(1)$$ There's nothing of depending or not depending here.

Comment: I finally understood :DD , thank you Timbuc for your patience to help me!

Comment: @Lucas Glad to know that. Anyway, it won't hurt to dedicate some time to read and dive a little more on the basics.